# Sharing admin passwords with coworkers in small IT company

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-recovery

We are a small IT provider with couple of employees. We'd like to share a lot of customer password data we need to maintain the customer services.

What password repository software there exist which could fulfill some of the requirements below

- Open source
- Which could be accessed via web browser (running on a server)
- Different user accounts
- Stores passwords encrypted and the encryption key separate from the database (though must be still on the server)
- Optionally integrated with Google Apps authentication
- Optionally two factor authentication

(Found this old question but it does not go in detail whether it meets these requirements or not [Sharing passwords in a small team](https://superuser.com/questions/260802/sharing-passwords-in-a-small-team) )

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/30080/whats-the-safest-online-password-system http://serverfault.com/questions/2186/password-manager-that-allows-syncing-accross-platforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying with KeePassX and Dropbox.

http://www.keepassx.org/

KeePassX creates an encrypted file you control, so it should be pretty safe for government tampering and such.